# Writing to csv file via django is adding the module name in the first cell of the file header

Tags: python, django, csv

I am currently trying to write to a csv file from Django given a list of headers and various data.  The file is being successfully created with one exception, the first cell is always showing the module info right before the value of the header and I'm not sure why.  I read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/) related to csv file outputting and modeled the code after it as indicated below:

```
file_name = '%s_success.csv' % file_name 
response = HttpResponse(csv, content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name
c = csv.writer(response)
headers = ['foo', 'bar', 'abc', '123']
c.writeheader(headers)
for row in data:
   ...
   ...
```

Result:

```
<module 'csv' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/csv.pyc'>foo, bar, abc, 123
```

I want:

```
foo, bar, abc, 123
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're including the module in the response:

```
response = HttpResponse(csv, content_type='text/csv')
```

Just try

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
```